# Como limpar o cache no Opera 12?

Tags: javascript, html, cache, debug

Então, estou desenvolvendo com foco no Opera 12, ele tem um depurador bem interessante, parecido com do Chrome, porém uma coisa que me aborrece muito é que o refresh não limpa o cache do browser, muitas vezes fechar a aba e abrir uma nova não limpa também.

Fechar o browser e abrir novamente, as vezes limpa, porém o que é mais certeiro é fecha-lo apagar a pasta de cache dele, depois abrir novamente. Apenas apagar a pasta e atualizar não funciona, ele cria um novo cache igual a página que estava carregada antes.

Alguém sabe como desativar o cache dos scripts carregados no Opera 12?

Comment: Já tentou o "ctrl + F5"? Não tenho certeza se esse atalho é válido no Opera 12, mas tenta aí.

Comment: @LucasNunes já tinha sim, praticamente todas combinações no teclado que vc possa imaginar hehe, desde ctrl + r até ctrl + shift + F5, mas nenhuma delas garantia, agora depois de desativar o cache usando as preferencias do Ctrl + F12, só funciona.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aperte <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> e você terá um menu de `Preferências`, navegue até a aba `Avançado` e no menu à esquerda selecione `Histórico` logo em seguida você verá um botão `Esvaziar Agora` clique nele e você terá limpado seu cache.

**Veja detalhadamente na imagem abaixo:**

[image: limpar cache opera 12]

Note que você tem algumas opções referente ao Cache, caso queira modificar, no seu caso é recomendável marcar a caixa `Esvaziar na saída` e selecionar `Nenhum` em `Cache de memória` e `Cache de disco`.

Nota: Acho que também pode te ajudar, se você ir no menu lateral esquerdo em `Armazenamento` e lá você terá uma Combo chamada `Usar cache de aplicativos` coloque para `Não`.

Comment: Show de bola cara! Nossa procurei pacas essas opções, mas não conhecia essa manha do `ctrl` + `F12` resolveu sim! Pra desenvolvimento isso é uma mão na roda. Novamente, obrigado.

Comment: Estou grato em ajuda-lo, o Ctrl + F12 não é bem uma manha sabe, na verdade, se você apertar Alt(que abre o menu do Opera) e ir em preferências você consegue chegar ali também :p porém eu gosto de atalhos sabe, o que seria a vida sem atalhos :)

Answer (score 1):

Tente isso no head da sua página para não armazenar o cache:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"> 
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"> 
<meta http-equiv="expires" content ="-1">
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente esse javascript no console (CTRL + SHIFT + J) para recarregar a página e refazer o cache:

```
location.reload(true);
```

Comment: No Opera 12 o CTRL + SHIF + J não abre console, ele pede pra criar uma conta, não sei do que. Mas isso funciona bem no Chrome, talvez venha funcionar no Opera 13 que é um fork do Chrome.